# ¿Como podría hacer una petición POST con CURL con php para este tipo de Autenticación?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer esta petición post por medio de curl, pero no me funcion, en las indicaciones dice esto:

I've got an API Key... How can I make an API request?
You can send your requests with an Authorization Header with a value like this: Authorization: apiKey {api_key}.

Example using curl:

curl -H "Authorization: apiKey {api_key}" https://api.connectif.cloud
Important notes
Connectif HTTP API is open, it means that we do not have to add your IP's in a whitelist.

Intente con esto:

```
curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.connectif.cloud/purchases/',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'apiKey: aquipusemiapi',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;

Pero me lanza que la autenticación no es correcta. Podrían apoyarme por favor.

Comment: El header es `Authorization`. `array('Authorization: apiKey <api_key>', ...`

Answer (score 2):

El header del ApiKey no es correcto. Debería de ser `'Authorization: apiKey aquipusemiapi'` en vez de `'apiKey: aquipusemiapi'`. El código quedaría así:

```
curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.connectif.cloud/purchases/',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: apiKey aquipusemiapi',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```